# Pre-configured Rails VPS hosting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, hosting

Can anyone recommend a Rails VPS host that offers everything pre-configured (like Heroku) and just let's you upload and run your app? Heroku becomes expensive really quick as you scale up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a VPS that is pre-configured, you can try something like these

1. http://www.turnkeylinux.org/rails
2. http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack

and then uploaded it to a VPS provider. I would recommend Linode.

Answer (score 0):

Any service will become expense as you scale up - if you want cheap the likes of Slicehost, Brightbox (UK) offer vanilla VPS boxes but you're going to be setting stuff up yourself and sacrificing scaling. Maybe have a look at dotcloud.com - little more reasonably priced TBH than heroku

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for cheap hosting then a vanilla vps is very easy to set up. Check out the tutorials at http://articles.slicehost.com/. It's a really satisfying experience and good to know if you're a developer.

I read a lot that heroku is expensive but one free dyno plus a shared db at $15 will serve a **lot** of pages. Utilising varnish more so.

Answer (score 0):

Depends exactly on what you want. Heroku is a great Platform as a Service offering. This means that they take care of administering the database, app server, etc. In turn, they are a bit more expensive as you scale and have restrictions on what you can and cannot run (to make it possible for them in turn to scale their operations)

If what you are looking is your own VPS, but with everything already setup, you can use BitNami (as pointed out in another answer by @Dex).  We recently released [BitNami Cloud Hosting](http://bitnami.org/cloud), which has a free tier and together with AWS free offering allows you to have a Ruby On Rails environment running on a small machine (600 Mb of RAM, 10Gb disk) completely for free. If you need to scale, then you need to pay for Amazon charges, etc. This is great for starting out. Check it out!